# Ajax запросы через setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ajax

В ежедневнике если он открыт в окне браузера а так же на телефоне, если с телефона добавить задачу то в браузере ничего не меняется, только при перезагрузке страницы, я придумал решить проблему через setTimeOut - то есть посылать Ajax запросы на получение задач с сервера и выводить их допустим каждые 30 секунд - вопрос в следующем: насколько это ресурсоемкая задача и стоит ли вообще так делать , может есть другие варианты. Я не очень разбираюсь и мне кажется что возможно это лишняя трата трафика и/или ресурсов телефона или компьютера.

Может есть какой нибудь способ чтобы приложение понимало что пользователь не пользуется приложением допустим 10 минут и запускать setTimeout только в этом случае?

Comment: как вариант рассмотрите socket.io: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlA-3jIfT-Q&list=PLsuEohlthXdkRSxJTkmTstWKHgBHsd3Dx&index=40

Comment: бекенд на php ? @Чайник

Comment: Да бэкэнд написан на PHP

Comment: фреймворки я не использую, стараюсь делать свои заготовки универсальными чтобы везде применять и с настройками.